# Chrome wont load my js script file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome, scripting

Here is a simple server i set up on my computer and all I am trying to do is load a script file in my html file.

```
var express=require('express');



  var app=express();
  app.listen(3000);

  app.use(express.static('/scripts'));

  app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
 });

 Here is my html file containing the script 

<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Async Javascript</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Web</h1>

  <!--scripts-->
 <script  src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I load it in chrome all i get is the following it I get this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome isn't able to find your file as it is looking for it at **localhost:3000**/scripts/app.js. What you want it to do is look for the file based on the location of the current folder to the relative path you have specified. You have two ways to fix this. In your Express code, add this:

```
app.get('/scripts/app.js', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/scripts/app.js');
});
```

That code means when the request for the file is sent to localhost:3000/scripts/app.js, it will send the app.js file from the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code into my own filesystem, except I made sure that the directory was set up correctly. It worked for me. Here's an image of what I got: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlFMo.png)

The problem is where you're saving either your HMTL file or your Javascript file. This line of code here:

```
 <script  src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Make sure your HTML file is not in the scripts directory, double check where it's being saved. Change either this line of code to point to where app.js is saved or change where your HTML file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you set up your express route you have to access the file like

```
 <script  src="app.js"></script>
```

alternatively you can change the route to

```
app.use('/scripts',express.static('scripts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am replying late but the question is unanswered and I myself faced this issue (404 not found error when the Base HTML called the custom JS script although the server path was correct) and struggled a bit to solve the problem. So posting a possible solution for the future readers.

The key to the solution is **Express does not allow serving static files, by default**. We need to specify the path for static files such as JS, CSS etc in the main server code (index.js or main.js). So a folder has to be designated as static in the NodeJS app directory. Remember that when a node app is executed,  the path of the main.js/index.js file location is considered the *web-root* or *root directory*. So this is what I did.
*my_app.use(my_express.static(__dirname + '/public'));*

Here __dirname is a Node.js global variable which represents the *web-root* or *root directory* and *'public'* is the name of the directory which stores all the static files which will be sent to the client(browser). The name of the folder could be anything btw.
So thereafter my custom JS script, which I  was calling from the base html(index.html), was accessible and the 404 error got resolved.